# 英語の引用に訳は必要？

Tags: 討議

回答に英語の文献をブロック引用した場合、その訳を完璧じゃないにしろ記載した方が良いのでしょうか（絶対必要ということはないと思いますが）。またもしそうならそれもブロック引用するべきでしょうか、それとも「」などで囲って回答者の個人的な訳だと記載すれば十分でしょうか。

Answer (score 5):

あった方が親切かとは思いますが、なくてもいいとは思います。

以前、英語での回答(質問ではなく)が許されるか？みたいなメタ投稿があって、その時の帰結が、英語でも構わない、だったと思うので、引用でも英語のみで問題はないと思います。

Answer (score 3):

あった方が良いと思います。でも自信がないなら記載しないほうがいいと思います。
訳の書き方はブロック引用、「」でもどっちでもいいと思います。
ただ、質問をコミュニティWikiにして(しなくてもいいが)編集してもらうなどしてもらえば良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

最終的にあったほうが良いと思いますが、回答者自身が英語に自身が無いなら、無くて良いと思います。
気になった人が訳を編集で付けてくれたら素晴らしいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

あった方が親切だとは思いますが、なくても読んでくれる人は読んでくれます。
訳を付ける場合、ご自身が翻訳したものとどこかに明記しておけば充分だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

あったほうがいいかと思います。
私的な意見になってしまいますが、
英語のドキュメントやフォーラムを英文のまま読んで理解できる人は
開発で実装に然程苦労しない方かと思います。

流石に質問者も表立って「読めないので翻訳してください」とは言いづらいかと思いますので
ここは和訳できる何方かが、ザックリでもいいので訳を編集・追記してあげればより解決がスムーズになるかと思います。